# can't uncheck the check box (hide content while checkbox is unchecked)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to hide div content while checkbox is unchecked. 
[Here's my code](https://jsfiddle.net/v581pypg/3/)

I've made almost the same function for the div with id "focus" (big grey frame):

```
document.getElementById("checkFocus").onchange = function() {

var one = document.getElementById("focus");
    if (document.getElementById("checkFocus").checked === true) {
        one.style.display = "block";
    }
    else one.style.display = "none";
}
```

And it works!

So, I don't understand why the next function doesn't works at all:

```
document.getElementById("checkMass").onchange = function() {

var elem = document.querySelector("PeriodicTable")
var mass = elem.querySelectorAll("div.element > div.mass");
    if (document.getElementById("checkMass").checked === true) {
        mass.style.display = "block";
    }
    else mass.style.display = "none";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elem.querySelectorAll("div.element > div.mass");` doesn't return a single element, it returns a collection of all matches.

That said you can't do `mass.style.display` on a array, only on a single element so you need to do

```
if (document.getElementById("checkMass").checked === true) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
        mass[i].style.display = "block";
    }
else {
    for (var i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
        mass[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

instead.

Comment: Good point, trough he might be confused by `querySelector("PeriodicTable")` vs `querySelector("#PeriodicTable")`

Comment: She needs both of our answers for it to work (I guess) :p

Comment: NP check Akxe's anwer too (+ you are missing a `;` after your querySelector).

Comment: Oops, I've made a mistake in querySelector(#id), thanks for attentiveness

Answer (score 1):

The `querySelector("Any CSS rule")` needs a rule, `.` signify class, `#` signify id, but you have `querySelector("PeriodicTable")`. Therefor you are looking for elements with tagname of `PeriodicTable`. Either use `document.getElementById('PeriodicTable')` or `querySelector("#PeriodicTable")`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector